# Trouble understanding decorator

Tags: python

I want to check if the user is authenticated before he/she can access the method, so I wrote a decorator named `authorize` but only the decorator code is executed and even if the user is authenticated, the method is not called after it.
here are the method and the decorator codes:

```
@authorize
def post(self, **kw):
    # store data in database after authentication done using @authorize


def authorize(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        secret_key = config.get('auth_secret_key')
        auth_message = config.get('auth_message')
        if 'HTTP_TOKEN' not in request.environ:
            abort(401, detail='Authentication failed', passthrough='json')
        gibberish = request.environ['HTTP_TOKEN']
        if triple_des(secret_key).decrypt(gibberish, padmode=2).decode() != auth_message:
            abort(401, detail='Authentication failed', passthrough='json')
    return wrapper
```

If user has authentication problem, `401` is raised and request is aborted but if he is authenticated, the `post` method is not called. BTW, its my first time writing decorator so I might be completely wrong. Thanks for any answers

Comment: You never call `f` inside `wrapper`, so when did you expect that to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually call the function within your wrapper.

```
f(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Oh, I thought decorators are called before the method is called. I didn't know I have to call the method myself. Thanks

Comment: Right, and if you want to insert new args or kwargs: `f(*args, overridden_kwarg=val, **kwargs)`. (If we wanted to be safe even if overridden_kwarg was already in kwargs, we'd have to use `kwargs['overridden_kwarg'] = newval`)